# Three-way data binding

Tags: c#, winforms, binding

Hi I want to bind a TrackBar's Value property to two objects' BrightnessPercentage Property. I get an error in doing so, can someone tell me how to accomplish a three-way binding between my TrackBar, and two objects?

```
class ImageProperties {
  public int BrightnessPercentage { get; set; }
}

class ImageDrawer {
  public int BrightnessPercentage { get; set; }
}

ImageProperties _imgProps = new ImageProperties();
ImageDrawer _imgDrawer = new ImageDrawer();

void Test() {
    trackBar1.DataBindings.Add("Value", _imgProps, "BrightnessPercentage", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);

    trackBar1.DataBindings.Add("Value", _imgDrawer, "BrightnessPercentage", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
class ImageProperties {      
  public int BrightnessPercentage { get; set; }
}

class ImageDrawer {
  public int BrightnessPercentage { get; set; }
}

ImageProperties _imgProps = new ImageProperties();
ImageDrawer _imgDrawer = new ImageDrawer();

public int TheBrightnessPercentage {
  get { return _imgProps.BrightnessPercentage;}
  set { _imgProps.BrightnessPercentage=_imgDrawer.BrightnessPercentage=value;}
}
void Test() {
    trackBar1.DataBindings.Add("Value", this, "TheBrightnessPercentage", false, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);    
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a simpler way? I have two dozen more properties, and I don't want to create an additional property for each one of those :/

Comment: Sorry, I can't get a better solution.